# Mapping response JSON to DTO in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, dto

I have API which returns JSON in this format:

```
{
"response": {
    "GeoObjectCollection": {
        "featureMember": [
            {
                "GeoObject": {
                    "Point": {
                        "pos": "37.611347 55.760241"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "GeoObject": {
                    "Point": {
                        "pos": "37.593965 55.771575"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

I want to convert this JSON object to the DTO model in Spring Boot App. How can I do that?

I need to create classes like response, GeoObjectCollection, GeoObject etc, or it's all made easier?

My app structure contains services, model, controllers.

Comment: That `pos` property is obnoxiously encoded. To be honest, in this case you're probably better off writing your own deserializer that takes care of parsing it into something useful (perhaps the `GeoJsonPoint` class, depending on what you're doing with it).

Comment: @chrylis, `pos` it is Geographic Coordinates. In general, this object contains more data, but specifically I need to pop out of it `pos`

Comment: It's probably best to write your own classes here. Static nested classes may make sense if this is a self-contained representation.